# Category Names Displaying Within View In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to do: I have an application that has 3 business categories: Business Development, Business Financial, And Business Admin.

I have an index view, localhost:3000/categories, which displays links to all of the above business categories.

They link to the new action, and the new view. Within that view, I have the following form code:

New.html.erb

```
<div align="center">
 <h1>What are your important <%= @category.bizdev %> Action items?</h1>

 <%= form_for @category do |f| %>
 <p>

 <p>Store Answer Below:</p>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 40, :style => 'height: 40px' %>
 </p>

 <p>
<%=f.submit 'Save action item' %>
</p>
<% end %> </div>
```

On the line: `<h1>What are your important <%= @category.bizdev %> Action items?</h1>`

I am trying to have the line list 1 of the 3 business categories (Business Development, Business Financial, Business Admin).

I've tried to create relationships between models: name, and category.

I cannot get the respective business category to display on the new view, for the form. Then, I need the form to submit the data to the respective category view (which I've been trying to do).

Categories controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @categories = Category.all
end

def new 
    @category = Category.new
    @bizdev = Name.new 
    Name.@bizdev = "Business Development"
end 

def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    @category.save
    redirect_to facilitates_path
end 

def show 
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end


def destroy
end 

private
def category_params
params.require(:category).permit(:answer)
end
end
```

Name Model

```
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category 
end
```

CategoriesHelper

```
module CategoriesHelper 

def bizdev
    bizdev = Name.new
    Name.bizdev = "Business Development"
end 

end
```

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :names 

end
```

Index View

```
<h1>Select A Business Category To Begin Identifying Action Items</h1>

<ol><li><%= link_to 'Business Admin', 'new' %></li><br><br>
<li><%= link_to 'Business Development/Marketing', 'new' %></li><br><br>
<li><%= link_to 'Financial', 'new' %></li>
</ol>


<%= link_to 'Store random action items', new_facilitate_path %><br><br>

<%= link_to 'See a list of already stored action items', facilitates_path %>
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :facilitates
resources :categories 

root 'categories#index'
get 'show' => 'facilitates#show'
get 'index' => 'categories#index'
get 'new' => 'categories#new'
get 'bizadmstor' => 'categories#bizadmstor'
get 'bizdevstor' => 'categories#bizdevstor'
get 'bizfinstor' => 'categories#bizfinstor'
get 'bizadmshow' => 'categories#bizadmshow'
get 'categories/show' => 'categories#show'
get 'categories/new' => 'categories#new'
```

Answer (score 1):

This `Name.@bizdev` obviously wrong. I guess you are trying to do next: `@category.names << @bizdev`.

Helper also incorrect:

```
bizdev = Name.new
bizdev.name = "Business Development" # i guess you have name property of this model
```

In general - `Name` is not an Instance of the class, it's class itself. And you can define its attributes, you can do this only for some instance of a class, like `bizdev` in this example.

In your example, you don't need a class `Name`, you need a property `name` for the class Category. Or if you what that it should be a class, also it should have property name, to return it. This `@category.bizdev` will return a class, not some value. Should be `@category.bizdev.name` or `@category.bizdev` if `bizdev` is a property.

Comment: OK - that being said, can you be more specific about exactly what to do?

Comment: add `name` to `Name` class.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm about 3 weeks into rails. Meaning = you really have to explain exactly what code to write. I'm trying many things in the meantime. In Category_params method:

def category_params
 params.require(:category).permit(:answer, :name) - which still throws error on view: Undefined method for name

Comment: Figured it out myself - created, in Category model: def name 
"Business Development"
end 

And then in view, called: @category.name

The next time you answer a question for anyone, understand that you have to be as specific as possible. People's brains do not learn from vague instructions. They learn with exact instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself - created, in Category model:

```
def name 
  "Business Development"
end
```

And then in view, called: `@category.name`

So - I had to create a method within my category model, called name, that simply writes "Business Development." Then, I called it via: `@category.name` in the new view.